# How to make different tables match using google spreadsheets? With a unnique I.D

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hello wonderful people from the internet.

I need your help. I am building a master  google spreadsheet at work that connects different departments. I have my main list (the one highlighted in red) and that one is only on the master spreadsheet and it is imported to other sheets but it can only be modified from the first one.

In the writing department they work with some clients but some of them they don't so when I get the information of what they worked in I get the one highlighted in green. In order for me to return the data to the master sheet I need to have it in order and with all the clients because if not the database it's not going to work.

**I need to know how to get the third table on the right that connects both the red and green tables.**

P.S I dont know if it's necessary but the red table is all imported from the main spreadsheet and the green table is using a quarry to get a resume from the writers work. If you have doubts about anything else please let me know and thank you for reading.

**The final table should look like the blue one in the second image**

[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

[image: Blue Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have `K:L` copy pasted from `A:B`, use `VLOOKUP`:

`M2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(K2:K,D2:I,{3,4,5,6},0)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you saved me.